# AHTabBarController not compatible with Swift

Tags: swift

I want to use the "AHTabBarController" in a swift project.

I don't know why this code isn't work:

```
        var tabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as AHTabBarController

        var tab1 = AHTabView()
        tab1.image = UIImage(named: "")
        tab1.title = "Tab 1"

        var tab1_subItem = AHSubitemView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        tab1_subItem.image = UIImage(named: "")
        tab1_subItem.title = "Tab 1 Title"
        tab1_subItem.viewControllerIdentifier = "channelsListSB"

        tab1.addSubitem(tab1_subItem)


        tabBarController.tabs.addObjectsFromArray([tab1])

        self.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
```

The objective-C code is:

```
AHTabBarController *tabBarController = (AHTabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController;

/******* PURUS *******/
AHTabView *purus = [AHTabView new];
[purus setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"persondot"]];
[purus setTitle:@"Purus"];

AHSubitemView *pFirst = [AHSubitemView new];
[pFirst setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"persondot"]];
[pFirst setTitle:@"First"];
[pFirst setViewControllerIdentifier:@"PurusFirst"];
[purus addSubitem:pFirst];

// …  

AHSubitemView *fFirst = [AHSubitemView new];
[fFirst setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photos"]];
[fFirst setTitle:@"First"];
[fFirst setViewControllerIdentifier:@"FringillaFirst"];
[fringilla addSubitem:fFirst];
//Don't forget to add your AHTabView instances to the AHTabBarController!
[tabBarController.tabs addObjectsFromArray:@[purus, fringilla, ipsum]];
```

The error is:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: *I don't know why this code isn't work* is a completely useless description. What does not work as excepted? What do you expect?

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Do you know what it means to unwrap an optional value? Which line causes this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify a line, so I'm just guessing that the issue is here:

```
tab1.image = UIImage(named: "")
```

This is returning `nil`, but you're assigning it to `image`, which is an implicitly unwrapped optional. You need to specify an actual image name that is guaranteed to return an image. Alternatively, you could do it conditionally:

```
if let image = UIImage(named: "") {
    tab1.image = image
} else {
    // handle failure
}
```

Comment: 2015-03-02 22:22:58.491 altelfaz[25005:2046895] CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: 
[25005:2046895] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid ViewController!', reason: 'The ViewController instantiated form the storyboard may not be nil. Please check if the identifier is valid'